# Rearranging columns and exIporting range to CSV

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data that is downloaded from SQL Server. Data can be huge. I need to rearrange it to a specific column order template before exporting it to either CSV or XLSX, really does not matter.

In this instance, I have put together a code that takes the original data (From Col A to Co; Q and set them up in the same sheet from Col T to Col AB) then attempt to export that range (T:AB to Last row) as CSV.

First part of the code works, pretty straightforward. However, I am struggling to export the range to either CSV or XLSX. Currently it is exporting data into another file only in row 1.

**CODE**

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim rngToSave As range
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim csvVal As String
LR = Sheets("AAP").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Sheets("AAP").range("T2:T" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("B2:B" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("U2:U" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("C2:C" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("V2:V" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("I2:I" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("W2:W" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("J2:J" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("X2:X" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("E2:E" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("Y2:Y" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("F2:F" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("Z2:Z" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("H2:H" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("AA2:AA" & LR).Value = Sheets("AAP").range("G2:G" & LR).Value
Sheets("AAP").range("AB2:AB" & LR).Value = "AA_FEES"

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
myCSVFileName = myWB.Path & "\" & "CSV-Exported-File-" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm") & ".csv"
csvVal = ""
fNum = FreeFile
Set rngToSave = range("T2:AB" & LR)

Open myCSVFileName For Output As #fNum

For i = 1 To rngToSave.Rows.count
    For j = 1 To rngToSave.Columns.count
        csvVal = csvVal & Chr(34) & rngToSave(i, j).Value & Chr(34) & ","
    Next
    Print #fNum, Left(csvVal, Len(csvVal) - 2)
    csvVal = ""
Next

Close #fileNumber

End Sub
```

Any advise how to make this more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what sheet are you on while running this procedure? If you on your sheet with data only in B-G then it will return 1 for this piece of code: Set rngToSave = range("T2:AB" & LR). Hence why your loop might only run from i = 1 to 1

Comment: I am running this on the same sheet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method to export that to a CSV would be to copy the worksheet to no destination. This creates a new workbook that is the new ActiveWorkbook with a single worksheet that is a copy of the original. After deleting columns A:S, SaveAs xlCSV.

```
...
workSheets("AAP").copy
with activeworkbook
    application.displayalerts = false
    .worksheets(1).range("A:S").entirecolumn.delete
    .saveas filename:=myCSVFileName, fileformat:=xlcsv
    .close savechanges:=false
    application.displayalerts = true
end with
```